# на macOs Safari в React при нажатии на кнопку звук не воспроизводится, а в обычном js файле все нормально

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let play = ()=>{

    let audio = new Audio("./d86cf5ae179617e.mp3")

    audio.play()

}
```

```
<button onClick={play}>Меню</button>
```

аудио файл хранится локально, при нажатии на кнопку он должен проигрываться, но в консоли получаю ошибку Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported. а вот если указать URL(с удаленного сервера) файла, то всё нормально.

В обычном js файле так же все нормально, а вот в JSX не работает

Comment: какие еще ошибки в консоли?

Comment: только та что я написал

Comment: проблема только в сафари?

Comment: во всех браузерах

Comment: как ты без реакта проверяешь? Где лежит сам файл при реакте?

Comment: файл лежит в одной директории с компонентом, в котором используется, а без реакта я сделал обычный Html и js и туда прописал код выше и в обычном js все работает

Comment: _файл лежит в одной директории с компонентом, в котором используется_ - тогда в таком виде работать не будет. такого файла просто нет по этому пути после сборки